# Need help setting up Click Limits on my API

Tags: php, mysql, api

I have an API where users are requesting ads from my server, and are being paid on ad clicks. The issue I am running into is that I have daily limits per user, but I have no way to limit the speed in which clicks can come in. Had one user send over 200 clicks in less then a minute, which is nearly impossible. Obviously blocking out this user will solve the problem, but I want to make sure it never occurs again. Currently, we only store the date, user, queries that day and clicks that day in our database, and are easily able to check if their daily limit has been reached, but the data does not provide us any insight to see the amount of clicks processed in X amount of time. Storing each click in a table one by one is out of the question as we  get over a million clicks an hour among all of our partners, and the added server costs wouldn't make it justifiable. Any insight on how we can track the amount of clicks during X amount of time per user would be great. Thanks Guys!

Comment: If you are paying based on clicks, you probably do have to store everything. But you don't have to make all data available real time.

Comment: How would you suggest I track the clicks per minute then? It's a ton of data to go through every single minute.

Comment: Well, if you look at how google adwords works, you can make changes, but most changes don't take affect immediately. That is because data is being processed separately (probably constantly) to allow for a fast lookup. A realtime query on some of their datasets would not be feasible.

Comment: Would it be feasible to limit the user to one click every 5 seconds (or 2 seconds or 10 seconds or whatever)? Then you'd only need to store the last click time for each user. When there's a new click just compare the current time to the "last click" time. For a one-every-five-seconds limit the condition would be `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP > Last_Click_Time + INTERVAL 5 SECONDS`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with mysql. It'll be a huge pain and its super inefficient. Take a look at [redis](http://redis.io/commands/incr) rate limiter.